# SBS 2008: Connected via VPN but can't access anything

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I have an SBS 2008 installation with VPN enabled. Port 1723 on the router is forwarding to SBS. In Windows XP I have setup a VPN connection and connected using my domain credentials. However neither end can ping each other.

I tried disabling the SBS firewall but to no avail.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check routing table on your XP client

Comment: I tried setting up the same VPN connection (PPTP) on my iPhone. It authenticates and says it's connected but still can't access anything.

Comment: So (as you can access clients from server) seems you have problems with routing on clients... Looks like your packets for server goes through your client's default network gateway, not through tunnel.

Comment: Sorry I got the ping bit wrong... SBS cannot ping the client. So when the VPN is connected, neither end can ping each other.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my local subnet had something to do with it. Was using 10.10.0.0/255.0.0.0. The remote subnet (of SBS) was 10.1.1.0/255.255.255.0.

When I changed my local subnet to 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0, everything worked as expected. Now I can use VPN via Windows XP and my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

note: If you would've just changed your original subnet mask from 255.0.0.0 to 255.255.0.0 or 255.255.255.0 you would've resolved this as well.